# How do I get a classic red-white heat map in tableau without the gray?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get a heat map (highlight table) in Tableau that fades naturally from white to red, without the gray in between. I created it in R Studio with the same data, but am having trouble reproducing it in Tableau.

I've tried creating a red sequential pallet, a red-white diverging color pallet, and customizing some of the default diverging color pallets. Customizing default color pallets gets me close, but it still contains gray for the lowest values.

Here's what I am getting:
[Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYtBB.png)

Here is what I want:
[Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5707.png)

Let me know if you need additional information. I can link the dataset in Tableau Public if needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option you have to create something more custom for your need is trying the custom palettes.

Try to take a look here:
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_create_custom_colors.htm

Essentially, you'll need to select the main level of your desired gradient, like this:

```
<color-palette name="Classic Red" type="ordered-sequential">
<color>#9c0824</color>
<color>#b10c1d</color>
<color>#c21417</color>
<color>#cf1719</color>
<color>#d8392c</color>
<color>#e35745</color>
<color>#f57667</color>
<color>#f89a90</color>
<color>#eac0bd</color>
</color-palette>
```